# happend when calling a method with param in groovy

Tags: groovy

My groovy version is 2.1.7

here is my code:

```
def repeat(val){
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        println val;
    }
}
repeat("Hello World")
```

When i run it, some exception throw. It only happened when i call the given method with param. If it is a method without param, everything is OK.

> Exception thrown 九月 29, 2013 5:38:49 下午
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize
>
> WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:
>
> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "2$repeat" in class
>   file 2$repeat
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.define(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:42)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:86)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.defineClassAndGetConstructor(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compilePogoMethod(CallSiteGenerator.java:217)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createPogoMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:228)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.createCachedMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:212)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.createPogoMetaMethodSite(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:188)
>
> at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPogoCallCurrentSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3121)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallCurrentSite(CallSiteArray.java:108)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>
> at 2.run(2.groovy:6)

Comment: How do you run your code? I've tested this and it works fine (with/without param). I Think you have some sort of configuration or runtime problem. The code is fine

Comment: This looks like a problem with class generation. That stacktrace sure is weird. Are you using... jdk8, maybe? What is your `java -version`? What is your groovy filename?

Comment: As you have your groovy code in a file called `2.groovy`, Groovy compiles this to a class called `2`.  This is not a valid classname.  However I cannot work out why it allows `def repeat(){}` or `def repeat( String val ){}`, but not `def repeat( val ){}` or `def repeat( Object val ){}`

Comment: This is a good question to ask the groovy-user mailing list

Answer (score 1):

I'm so stupid.I name this class to begin with a number.